# Half-Exponential Function

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, function

A [half-exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-exponential_function) is one which when composed with itself gives an exponential function. For instance, if `f(f(x)) = 2^x`, then `f` would be a half-exponential function. In this challenge, you will compute a specific half-exponential function.

Specifically, you will compute the function from the non-negative integers to the non-negative integers with the following properties:

- Monotonically increasing: if `x < y`, then `f(x) < f(y)`
- At least half-exponential: For all `x`, `f(f(x)) >= 2^x`
- Lexicographically smallest: Among all functions with the above properties, output the one which minimizes `f(0)`, which given that choice minimizes `f(1)`, then `f(2)`, and so on.

The initial values of this function, for inputs `0, 1, 2, ...` are:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 32, 64, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 256, 257, ...]`

You may output this function via any of the following methods, either as a function or as a full program:

- Take `x` as input, output `f(x)`.
- Take `x` as input, output the first `x` values of `f`.
- Infinitely output all of `f`.

If you want to take `x` and output `f(x)`, `x` must be zero indexed.

[Reference implementation](https://tio.run/##bZFNboMwEIX3nGKSla02iJ@qCxPSW3SDUGSldmOJTJBtkqiIs1MbKA1tvBnPm8/PM7ZujO17iXDkldyLW02QQWPUl6Cw2cG7OGyHbAdtAG5VwsKpsSDZfS2HizisiigDLLOBUxIQ8hwiaEEL22gECd1QkkVUuhPxEowfgbEHkyWYPAITD6YjKM8aFCiENAxxansykIUqp65meTTwug8bd@XTT29@dfPOjy73auTKbOHr5C3gP1ene1@SADfQvL7QsD5fiRqyNKFD9C/457ZpqqALAvczJ66Q0Pv35zdnauwHYwIvjHH9aQgN0R5JTMMGr5rXLq@5NoL8CtlsIN3x@b@d21SqtUJb4YqsW/bWrZ9BukIX9H2fRN8)

This is code golf - shortest code in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are banned, as always.

Comment: seems definition is not verified for 0 : f(f(0)) = f(1) = 2 but 2^0 = 1

Comment: and for 1 :  f(f(1)) = f(2) = 3 but 2^1 = 2

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul the requirement is f(f(x)) **>=** 2^x.

Comment: Should we submit to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)?

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>51</s> 48 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Arnauld*

```
f=i=>i?f[f[q=f(i-1),r=f[i]||q+1]=(i>1)<<i,i]=r:1
```

Takes in **n** and outputs the **n**'th item in the sequence.

---

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 64 bytes

```
f=(n,a=[],q=1)=>n?f(n-1,a,(n=2**a.indexOf(a.push(q)))<++q?q:n):a
```

A recursive function that takes in `x` and returns the first `x` items of the sequence as an array.

#### How it works

The array **a** is procedurally generated, one item at a time, until it reaches the desired length. (A port of the infinite technique used in [xnor's excellent Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150067/42545) would likely be shorter.)

We can make the following observation for each index **i** (0-indexed):

- If **i** exists as an item in **a** at index **j** (**a[j] = i**), then **a[i]** needs to be at least **2<sup>j</sup>**.

This is true because **f(f(j))** needs to be at least **2<sup>j</sup>**, and **f(f(j))** is equivalent to **a[a[j]]**, which is in turn equivalent to **a[i]**.

Normally the correct option is exactly **2<sup>j</sup>**. However, for the singular case **i = 2**, **2** exists in the array at index **j = 1**, which means that **2<sup>j</sup>** would be **2**—but this means that we would have **2** at both **a[1]** and **a[2]**. To get around this, we take the maximum of **2<sup>j</sup>** and **a[i-1] + 1** (one more than the previous item), which gives **3** for **i = 2**.

This technique also happens to take care of deciding whether or not **j** exists—if it doesn't, JS's `.indexOf()` method returns **-1**, which leads to taking the max of **a[i-1] + 1** and **2<sup>-1</sup> = 0.5**. Since 
all items in the sequence are at least **1**, this will always return the previous item plus one.

(I'm writing this explanation late at night, so please let me know if something is confusing or I missed anything)

Comment: Note that inputs `272` and up give incorrect answers due to integer overflow issues. This is fine, as it works up to the limit of the datatype.

Comment: Use `2**` instead of `1<<` hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: Now the `.99` kills the solution. But why using `+.99` and not just `+.9`? What's the difference?

Comment: @user202729 I feel like an idiot--that was left in there from a previous version where I was using `Math.log2(...)` and had to calculate the ceiling. Now it's not needed at all. Thanks! I'll look into the `2**` thing--I was using `2**...+.99|0` originally, but `1<<` was shorter because I didn't need the `|0`. Now I think there's no difference...

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
d={};a=n=1
while 1:print a;a=d.get(n,a+1);d[1%n*a]=2**n;n+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8W2utY60TbP1pCrPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCERKJqil55aopGnk6htqGmdEm2omqeVGGtrpKWVZ52nbWv4/z8A)

Prints forever.

---

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=2:n<1or(i>=n)*-~f(n-1)or(f(i)==n)<<i or f(n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcw7DoAgEIThq2zJ@iiW0oB3wSi6iQ6G2Nh4ddxyvkz@@32OAt9ajme6ljURBo1@QpBSnc4R3I1fdhiFDbJTjmYhKJVK5oP2wi3bACmoJuybE@HprorHavbh9gM)

A function. Outputs `True` in place of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 53 + 1 (`-p`) = 54 bytes

```
$\=$_>0;map$a[$\=$a[$_]?2**$a[$_]:$\+1]=$_,++$\..$_}{
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlYl3s7AOjexQCUxGsQDkvGx9kZaWhCWlUqMtmEsUJGOtrZKjJ6eSnxt9f//hub/8gtKMvPziv/rFgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 66 bytes

```
for((r=$1?2:1,i=2;i<=$1;i++));{ a[r=a[i]?2**a[i]:r+1]=$i;};echo $r
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEOjyFbF0N7IylAn09bIOtMGyLPO1NbW1LSuVkiMLrJNjM6MtTfS0gLRVkXahrG2KpnWtdapyRn5CipF////NzQHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
iL’2*»Ṁ‘$ṭ
⁸Ç¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//aUzigJkyKsK74bmA4oCYJOG5rQrigbjDh8Kh//8xOA)

#### How it works

```
⁸Ç¡         Main link. No arguments.

⁸           Set the left argument and the return value to [].
 Ç¡         Read an integer n from STDIN and call the helper link n times, first on
            [], then on the previous result. Return the last result.


iL’2*»Ṁ‘$ṭ  Helper link. Argument: A (array)

 L          Take the length of A. This is the 0-based index of the next element.
i           Find its 1-based index in A (0 if not present).
  ’         Decrement to a 0-based index (-1 if not present).
   2*       Elevate 2 to the 0-based index.
      Ṁ‘$   Take the maximum of A and increment it by 1.
            Note that Ṁ returns 0 for an empty list.
     »      Take the maximum of the results to both sides.
         ṭ  Tack (append) the result to A.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 111 bytes

```python
def f(x):
 a=range(1,2**x)
 for i in range(1,x):a[i]=max(a[i],a[i-1]+1);a[a[i]]=max(a[a[i]],2**i)
 return a[:x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0LTiksh0bYoMS89VcNQx0hLq0KTSyEtv0ghUyEzTwEmDlSWGJ0Za5ubWKEBYugACV3DWG1DTevEaJAATArMBhmTCTSmKLWktChPITHaqiL2f0FRZl4J0EYjA83/AA)

This is a significant modification of [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729)'s answer. I would have posted this improvement as a comment, but the answer is deleted and so comments are disabled.

Comment: This fails with a "list index out of range" exception on the input 258. I think the problem is that `x**2` is too small.

Comment: Well... Python 2 is different (often less bytes) from Python 3.

Comment: As expected, half-exponential is way larger than quadratic. The solution get "list index out of range" at `x=1000`. You may want to try `2**x` - terribly large, but codegolf is codegolf.

Comment: @user202729 Ah, this is true. Unfortunately it now encounters an entirely different problem with larger inputs in that `2**x` creates far too large of a range for Python to continue.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 137 bytes

```
func f(n:Int){var l=Array(1...n).map{$0>3 ?0:$0},p=8;if n>3{for i in 3..<n{if l[i]<1{l[i]=l[i-1]+1};if l[i]<n{l[l[i]]=p};p*=2}};print(l)}
```

Takes input as `Int` (integer) and prints as `[Int]` (integer array).

### Ungolfed version

```
func f(n:Int){
    var l = Array(1...n).map{$0 > 3 ? 0 : $0} // Create the range from 1 to n and set all
    var p = 8                                 // values greater than 3 to 0
    if n > 3 {
        for i in 3 ..< n {
            if l[i] < 1 {
                l[i] = l[i - 1] + 1
            }
            if l[i] < n {
                l[l[i]] = p
            }
            p *= 2
        }
    }
    print(l)
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what will happen if you remove the space before the `?`?

Comment: @ETHproductions That leads to a compiler error, since integers can't be [optional chained](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).